# What is the relationship between presented classes?

Tags: c++, oop, aggregation, composition, relationships

In the code below I've mentioned relationships between classes. Are they correct?

```
class D
{
public:
    D(C &c) : c_(c) {
    }
private:
    C &c_; // D compositions C ?? Please make me correct if i am wrong.
};
class C
{

};
void function(C &c)
{
    D d(c);// main composition D
}
int main()
{
    C c; // main composition C
    function(c);

}
```

Comment: I asked to make me correct about my code comments and my understanding also.

Comment: Anybody can answer of this question?